# Binding capslock key to a shell script

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

A linux newbie here! I own a netbook which doesn't have any indicator leds. So I decided to write a small shell script that would notify me when the capslock key is pressed. The script goes something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
state=$(xset -q | grep Caps | awk '{print $4}')
if [ "$state" = "on" ]
then
notify-send "Caplock :ON"
fi
```

Now I want to bind the script to the capslock key so that it gets executed everytime I press the key. But the keyboard shortcuts setting expects a key combination. Is it possible to bind it to just the capslock key??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11575559&postcount=2) forum post. It may be able to help you assuming you're using Unity. You'll have to install compizconfig-settings-manager first though.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.